# how to check embedding length of token in any pre-trained model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, embedding, word-embedding

how to check the embedding length of token in any pre-trained model??
I am working with a transformer and want to know the length of the embedding vector

how to find matrix size (number of tokens and size of each tokens)

Comment: Which embedding are you referring to, and for what model? Are you looking for the literal first layer embedding, or what is traditionally understood as the "embedding of a token" (i.e., the final hidden state size, or aggregate over multiple layers)?

Comment: I'm talking about first embedding- we pass text as an input, that text converted into token and each token has its own token id with respect to vocabulary, now each token can be represented by one embedding vector- how do I check that embedding size? I'm working with PEGASUS model

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.config` attribute:

```
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(codebert, num_labels = 2)
model.config
```

Output:

```
RobertaConfig {
  "_name_or_path": "microsoft/codebert-base",
  "architectures": [
    "RobertaModel"
  ],
  "attention_probs_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "bos_token_id": 0,
  "classifier_dropout": null,
  "eos_token_id": 2,
  "hidden_act": "gelu",
  "hidden_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "hidden_size": 768,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "intermediate_size": 3072,
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-05,
  "max_position_embeddings": 514,
  "model_type": "roberta",
  "num_attention_heads": 12,
  "num_hidden_layers": 12,
  "output_past": true,
  "pad_token_id": 1,
  "position_embedding_type": "absolute",
  "transformers_version": "4.31.0",
  "type_vocab_size": 1,
  "use_cache": true,
  "vocab_size": 50265
}
```

From documentations:

> hidden_size ( int , optional, defaults to 768) – Dimensionality of the
> encoder layers and the pooler layer.